# Debug Magento speed - slow on 'All' products select

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, debugging, pagination

I have around 80 products in my store - on selecting 'ALL' from the tool bar on the product list.phtml page the site is very slow to respond (and sometimes doesn't). Where do I start debugging this issue?

Strangely if I change the default value to 'ALL' in configuration the category loads OK. It seems to have the problem if I change from, for example 12 products to viewing 'all' products from the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AOE Profiler module on GitHub. It will give you an accurate breakdown on how the page is loaded:

[image: AOE Profiler]

Once you find the problem area you can investigate further.